# jQuery validate addMethod with two selects

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to write a new validation method for the jQuery validate plugin. I have two select boxes and I want to throw and error when both have the value of `yes` selected?

I've tried a couple of different methods but I can't get anything to work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$.validator.addMethod('noDuplicate0', function(value, element, params) {     
      value = $.makeArray($(element).val()) || [];
      var other = $.makeArray($(input[name=nightFreeRoomOnly]).val()) || []; 
      return $.inArray('0', value) == -1 || $.inArray('0', other) == -1; },'Both options can not be set to yes');
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You should see how equalTo validator is implemented, need to do the opposite

Comment: Why not use a `radio` control if you are trying to make some mutually exclusive selections?

Comment: here is what I have tried $.validator.addMethod('noDuplicate0', function(value, element, params) {
         value = $.makeArray($(element).val()) || [];
         var other = $.makeArray($(input[name=nightFreeRoomOnly]).val()) || [];
         return $.inArray('0', value) == -1 || $.inArray('0', other) == -1;
     },'Both options can not be set to yes');

Comment: @JamesPrivett You can edit your question to add more details, no need to use comments for that :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your own custom rule.

To add the `notEqual` method

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, params) { 
 return (value != $(param).find('option:selected').val() || value!='yes');
}, jQuery.format("Values A and B Cannot be equal"));
```

And then run this custom method from your validation

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
   A: "required",
   B: {
      notEqual: "#A"
   }
 }
});
```

where A and B are your 2 select field ids

Comment: I don't think that covers the question - OP is trying to only have validation fail if both are `yes` not if they are the same (i.e. both `no` should be OK)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track... use `addMethod`.  If your form looks like this:

```
<form id="myform">
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option selected="selected">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option selected="selected">yes</option>
    <option>no</option>
</select>    
<br><input type="submit">
</form>​
```

You could make a validate script like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('notbothyes', function(val, el, param) {
    return (val != 'yes' || ('yes' != $(param).find('option:selected').val()));
}, 'These fields cannot both be yes');

$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        select1: {
            notbothyes: '#select2'
        },
        select2: {
            notbothyes: '#select1'
        }
    }
});
```

See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/FtUPq/1/